# Finding $P(\overline{A} \cup B)$ when $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A \cup B$) is known

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> Two events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A) = 0.2$, $P(B) = 0.3$ and
> $P(A \cup B) = 0.4$.
> (a) Find $P(A \cap B)$.
> (b) Find $P(\overline{A} \cup B)$.

Answer:(a)
Recall that:
$$ P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A \cup B) $$
We have:
\begin{align*}
-P(A \cap B) &= P(A \cup B) - P(A) - P(B) \\
P(A \cap B) &= -P(A \cup B) + P(A) + P(B) \\
P(A \cap B) &= -0.4 + 0.2 + 0.3 \\
P(A \cap B) &= 0.1 \\
\end{align*}
(b)
\begin{align*}
P(A) + P(\overline{A}) &= 1 \\
P(\overline{A}) &= 1 - P(A) = 1 - 0.1 \\
P(\overline{A}) &= 0.9 \\
P(\overline{A} \cup B) &= P(\overline{A}) + P(B) - P(\overline{A} \cap B) 
\end{align*}
Now I am stuck because I do not know how to find $P(\overline{A} \cap B)$.

Now, based upon the comments from lulu, I have:
\begin{align*}
P(A \cap B) + P(\overline{A} \cap B) &= P(B) \\
.1 + P(\overline{A} \cap B) &= .4 \\
P(\overline{A} \cap B) &= 0.3 \\
P(\overline{A} ) &= 0.8 \\
P(\overline{A} \cup B) &= 0.8 + 0.4 - 0.3 \\
P(\overline{A} \cup B) &= 0.9 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Well, what event is "$A\cap B$ or $\overline A\cap B$"?

Comment: Right.  And $A\cap B$ and $\overline A\cap B$ are disjoint, so...

Comment: @lulu I do not know

Comment: If $E,F$ are disjoint events, what is $P(E\cup F)$?

Comment: If $E$ and $F$ are disjoint events then $P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F)$.

Comment: Ok....so now just put it all together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129084/discussion-between-bob-and-lulu).

Comment: There is nothing to chat about.  Just look at your first comment and use the fact that the two events involved in the union are disjoint.

Comment: Oh, hold on.  You altered your first comment, though it was  right the first time.  That union is not empty, rather it is $B$.

Comment: @lulu Are you trying to tell me that $P(A \cap B) + P(\overline{A} \cap B) = P(B)$?

Comment: Of course.  That's clear, is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are both correct. Alternatively, a Venn diagram helps with the set algebra.

[image]

1. $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$
    So, $P(A\cap
       B)=0.2+0.3-0.4=0.1.$
2. $P(\overline{A} \cup B)=P(B)+P(\overline{A\cup B})=0.3+(1-0.4)=0.9.$